# AngularJS Radio button and checkbox not binding to model

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax, angularjs-directive

I'm working on business hours of operation where the user can select a day and choose its operation hours or choose "closed" radio btn and let the fromTime and toTime be set as closed.
If he chooses "Apply to all Weekdays" the whatever time he selected for Monday or any day will be applied to all weekdays.
By default set time for weekdays is 7:00 am to 3:00pm and Saturday, Sunday as closed. These values needs to be posted to server in

```
[{
  Day:  string,
  fromTime: string, 
  toTime: string
}]
```

These operations are not functioning as expected. I tried to simulate in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/priyaa2002/t3ysqn4e/6/). But couldn't make it work there. Screen shot is captured from my live project. Radio buttons are functioning to display the value.

[image: screenshot]

```
<div class="controls">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-xl-9">
    <div ng-repeat="list in vm.weekdays" ng-init="thisIndex = $index">
      <div class="control-group" id="from-to">
        <div class="controls">

          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 radio-days">
            <label class="radio inline aid-radio-days-lbl radio-days" for="aid-radio-{{list.Day}}">
              {{list.Day}}
              <input type="radio" class="radio-days" name="{{list.Day}}" id="aid-radio-{{list.Day}}" value="{{list.name}} ng-model="vm.closed[thisIndex]">
            </label>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 select-time">
            <time-picker ng-model="vm.weekdays.fromTime" id="aid-from-{{$index}}" name="fromTime"></time-picker>
            <span>&nbsp;To &nbsp;</span>
            <time-picker ng-model="vm.weekdays.toTime" id="aid-to-{{$index}}" name="to"></time-picker>
          </div>
          <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-12 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 radio-closed">
            <label class="radio inline aid-radio-days-lbl" for="aid-radio-closed-{{list.Day}}">
              <input type="radio" name="{{list.Day}}" id="aid-radio-closed-{{list.Day}}" ng-model="vm.closed[thisIndex]" ng-change="vm.setClosed($index)"> Closed
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 all-week-chkbox">
    <label class="checkbox inline aid-radio-days-closed-lbl">
      <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1" ng-model="vm.closed" ng-change="vm.setAllWeekdayClosed($index)"> Apply to all weekdays
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
(function() {
'use strict'; 
    angular.module('agencyApp')
    .controller('HoursController',HoursController)
    .directive('timePicker', timePicker);

  function HoursController () {
    var vm = this;
    vm.setClosed = setClosed;
    vm.setAllWeekdayClosed = setAllWeekdayClosed;
    vm.weekdays = [
                    {Day: 'Monday', fromTime: "7:00 am", toTime: "3:00 pm"},
                    {Day: 'Tuesday',fromTime: "7:00 am", toTime: "3:00 pm"},
                    {Day: 'Wednesday',fromTime: "7:00 am", toTime: "3:00 pm"},
                    {Day: 'Thursday',fromTime: "7:00 am", toTime: "3:00 pm"},
                    {Day: 'Friday',fromTime: "7:00 am", toTime: "3:00 pm"},
                    {Day: 'Saturday', fromTime: "closed", toTime: "closed"},
                    {Day: 'Sunday', fromTime: "closed", toTime: "closed"}
                ];

    function setClosed(index) {
            if (vm.closed[index]) {
                vm.weekdays[index].toTime = vm.weekdays[index].fromTime = 'closed';
            }
            if (!vm.closed[index]) {
                vm.weekdays[index].fromTime = '7:00 am';
                vm.weekdays[index].toTime = '3:00 pm';
            }
        };

        function setAllWeekdayClosed(index) {
            if (vm.closed[index]) {
                vm.weekdays[index].toTime = vm.weekdays[index].fromTime = 'closed';
            }
            if (!vm.closed[index]) {
                vm.weekdays[index].fromTime = '7:00 am';
                vm.weekdays[index].toTime = '3:00 pm';
            }
        };

  }

  function timePicker (){
        var ddo = {
            template: '<select class="input-small" ng-options="time as time for time in timings"></select>',
            restrict: 'E',
            require: 'ngModel',
            replace: true,
            compile: compileFn
        };
        return ddo;

        function compileFn(tElement, tAttrs) {
            tElement.attr('ng-model', tAttrs.ngModel);
            //tElement.attr('ng-disabled', tAttrs.ngModel + ' === "closed"');
            return linkFn;  
        };

        function linkFn(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.timings = ['12:15 am', '12:30 am', '12:45 am', 
                '1:00 am', '1:15 am', '1:30 am', '1:45 am', 
                '2:00 am', '2:15 am', '2:30 am', '2:45 am',
                '3:00 am', '3:15 am', '3:30 am', '3:45 am',
                '4:00 am', '4:15 am', '4:30 am', '4:45 am',
                '5:00 am', '5:15 am', '5:30 am', '5:45 am',
                '6:00 am', '6:15 am', '6:30 am', '6:45 am', 
                '7:00 am', '7:15 am', '7:30 am', '7:45 am', 
                '8:00 am', '8:15 am', '8:30 am', '8:45 am', 
                '9:00 am', '9:15 am', '9:30 am', '9:45 am',
                '10:00 am', '10:15 am', '10:30 am', '10:45 am',
                '11:00 am', '11:15 am', '11:30 am', '11:45 am',
                '12:00 pm', '12:15 pm', '12:30 pm', '12:45 pm', 
                '1:00 pm', '1:15 pm','1:30 pm', '1:45 pm', 
                '2:00 pm', '2:15 pm', '2:30 pm', '2:45 pm',
                '3:00 pm', '3:15 pm', '3:30 pm', '3:45 pm', 
                '4:00 pm', '4:15 pm','4:30 pm', '4:45 pm',
                '5:00 pm', '5:15 pm','5:30 pm', '5:45 pm',
                '6:00 pm', '6:16 pm','6:30 pm', '6:45 pm',
                '7:00 pm', '7:15 pm','7:30 pm', '7:45 pm',
                'closed'
            ];
        };
    }
})();
```

Comment: please be more specified about `These operations are not functioning as expected`. also post your controller code please.

Comment: [Pengyy] -- my controller code is in codepen. These functions refers to : the user can select a day and choose its operation hours or choose "closed" radio btn and let the fromTime and toTime be set as closed. If he chooses "Apply to all Weekdays" the whatever time he selected for Monday or any day will be applied to all weekdays. By default set time for weekdays is 7:00 am to 3:00pm and Saturday, Sunday as closed. These values needs to be posted to server in [ { Day: string, fromTime: string, toTime: string }]

Comment: 1. Each radio button closed should set a value per day. That would make sense, but all your radio buttons are bound to `vm.closed`. I think you should have an array on your vm and access the current day using $index.

Your setClosed function is checking `vm.closed[index]` but your ng-model is simply `vm.closed`, should be `vm.closed[$index]`.

Comment: Thats a completely different fiddle

Comment: here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/priyaa2002/t3ysqn4e/2/

Comment: that fiddle is broken for two reasons
1. the body tag for the html section (click the gear icon) is pointing to an app that doesnt exist - ExampleApp
2. you should initialize your app this way `angular.module('agencyApp', [])`

Comment: you can use `ng-value` in conjunction with `ng-model` to set the open/closed states. See this fiddle, the rest of what you're trying to do should be straight forward. Also I would recommend combining the models (days and closed) into one and advice against `ng-init`  http://jsfiddle.net/bowofola/k1492ucq/ 

good luck!

Comment: @Bowofola -- I have until this part done already in my project. I'm new to angular. I kinda got stuck in setting the select box value base on radio button options. I would appreciate your help on that. thanks for fixing my fiddles as well

Comment: Okay I'll post an answer explaining how to handle my-model, ng-value, ng-repeat and manual setting of models. That way you have enough to push you on. Should come with a working fiddle...

Comment: Almost done. I dont understand "whatever time he selected for Monday or any day will be applied to all weekdays." Please explain more. Latest fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bowofola/k1492ucq/

Comment: thanks bowofola for your time. It works